# Receive Objects from Firebase RealTime DB in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, mapping

I just want to get objects from firebase and cast them to Poll Object in Flutter. This is my Poll class:

```
class Poll {
  Poll({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.description,
    this.questions,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String description;
  List<Question> questions;

  factory Poll.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Poll(
        name: json['name'],
        description: json['description'],
        questions: List<Question>.from(
            json['questions'].map((x) => Question.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'description': description,
        'questions': List<dynamic>.from(questions.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}
```

And this is my Question Class:

```
class Question {
  String id;
  String question;
  String customAnswer;
  //Map<String, bool> possibleAnswers;

  //constructor, for Question with one or multiple answer possibilities
  //Question({this.question, this.possibleAnswers});

  // constructor, for a input field (basicly custom answer)
  Question.customAnswer({
    this.id,
    this.question,
    this.customAnswer,
  });

  factory Question.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) =>
      Question.customAnswer(
        question: json['question'],
        customAnswer: json['customAnswer'],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'question': question,
        'customAnswer': customAnswer,
      };
}
```

Here is a screenshot from my Realtime DB:
[image]

The question is how i should cast the dataSnapshot to my Poll inside of this code snippet:

```
dbRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      //cast here
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research i found this solution, it has worked in my case:

```
void getPolls() {
    dbRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      polls = _parseData(snapshot);
    });
  }

  List<Poll> _parseData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    var companyList = <Poll>[];
    var mapOfMaps = Map<String, dynamic>.from(dataSnapshot.value);

    mapOfMaps.values.forEach((value) {
      companyList.add(Poll.fromJson(Map.from(value)));
    });
    return companyList;
  }
```